# Is there any difference in meaning and usage between "granted", "admittedly" and "to be sure"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

Could you tell me if there is there any difference in meaning and usage between "granted", "admittedly" and "to be sure"? For example:

> I've passed the exam, **granted**, it was not easy.
>
> I've passed the exam, **admittedly**, it was not easy.
>
> I've passed the exam, **to be sure**, it was not easy.

Comment: Ps these are all comma splices and it should be “not easy” at the end.

Comment: "no easy" is not English. ["It was **no easy feat**"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/example/english/easy-feat) is a common idiom and fixed phrase but I don't see any "feat" there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your sentences are run-on and not grammatical. They could be corrected by inserting the conjunction "though", like this:
`I've passed the exam, though, granted, it was not easy.`

But, here is a better illustration of the use of the expressions. They are all concessive in this sense:

[American Heritage Dictionary "concessive"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=concessive)
2. Grammar:  Expressing concession, as the conjunction *though*.

To justify the concessive meaning, there needs to be a strong contrast between what was stated and what was conceded. The expressions you mention work better as sentence adverbs in separate sentences, for example,
`I passed the exam with flying colors. Admittedly, it was not a difficult exam.`

In this example, the first sentence brags about the high grade I received, while the second sentence admits (concedes) that it's not much of a reason to brag, because the exam was easy.

In that use, all three of the expressions you ask about would have the same meaning.